Newly installed Spyder: Kernel doesn't start
I have a fresh Spyder install via miniconda:
conda create -c conda-forge -n spyder-env spyder numpy scipy pandas matplotlib sympy cython
conda activate spyder-env
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict

Version information:
    Spyder version: 5.5.3 (conda)
    Python version: 3.12.2 64-bit
    Qt version: 5.15.8
    PyQt5 version: 5.15.9
    Operating System: Windows-11-10.0.22631-SP0

However, on launching spyder (from the start menu or the conda console), the kernel does not start. Either I get an eternally looping "connecting to kernel" message, or the following error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console_main_.py", line 24, in
start.main()
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 319, in main
kernel.initialize()
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 118, in inner
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 692, in initialize
self.init_sockets()
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 331, in init_sockets
self.shell_port = self._bind_socket(self.shell_socket, self.shell_port)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 253, in _bind_socket
return self._try_bind_socket(s, port)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 229, in _try_bind_socket
s.bind("tcp://%s:%i" % (self.ip, port))
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 302, in bind
super().bind(addr)
File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 564, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind
File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 28, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Address in use (addr='tcp://127.0.0.1:57809')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in run_code
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console_main.py", line 24, in
start.main()
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 319, in main
kernel.initialize()
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 118, in inner
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 692, in initialize
self.init_sockets()
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 331, in init_sockets
self.shell_port = self._bind_socket(self.shell_socket, self.shell_port)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 253, in _bind_socket
return self._try_bind_socket(s, port)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 229, in _try_bind_socket
s.bind("tcp://%s:%i" % (self.ip, port))
File "C:\ProgramData\miniforge3\envs\spyder‑env\Lib\site‑packages\zmq\sugar\socket.py", line 302, in bind
super().bind(addr)
File "zmq/backend/cython/socket.pyx", line 564, in zmq.backend.cython.socket.Socket.bind
File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 28, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
zmq.error.ZMQError: Address in use (addr='tcp://127.0.0.1:57809')

UPDATE
I can get a working sypder if I use an older spyder version: With
conda create -c conda-forge -n spyder-old-env spyder=5.4 numpy scipy pandas matplotlib sympy cython

I can start spyder without issue in the spyder-old-env environment.
So maybe there`s a bug in the current version?
